# Detect Blocked popups without opening a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

This question has been raised many times on "How to check if the popup is blocked on my browser or not" and all the solutions that i found have proposed a solution where a new popup window is opened for testing.

> References:
>
> 1. "[Detect blocked popup in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668286/detect-blocked-popup-in-chrome)"
> 2. "[How can I detect if a browser is blocking a popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914/how-can-i-detect-if-a-browser-is-blocking-a-popup/2917#2917)"

etc.

I would like to know if there is any possibility of knowing a blocked popup, without actually opening one.

Because due to many reasons the test pop up may take time to close, which looks ugly on start-page of your application.

For example if we could use anything from the request header from the client, to know the popup preferences etc like we can get for the language preferences.

It'll be a huge help. Thanks

Comment: Work around - I have put the popup detection test code with a cookie. So that the test is performed once a month if the popups are not blocked. Also, i have reduced the window size to make it least noticeable as possible.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, popup blockers works by overwrite a `window.open` function and in most cases return a `null`. So one way is to detect if `window.open` is still nativ function.

You can test that with `toString` method, which return `[native code]` as a body of that function. `toString` not work in old IE, so instead of that use `''+` to convert function.

`var havePopupBlockers = ('' + window.open).indexOf('[native code]') === -1;`

This is not silver bullet, but can detect potential risk. I test this on Chrome, FF, IE8 and IE9 with some various popup blockers and works.

Comment: This is an interesting technique. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: What is native code? How can i get from the browser?

Comment: @HasmukhBaldaniya When you convert some native function in string, function content is presented as `[native code]`. For example:
`'' + window.open  // return  'function open() { [native code] }'`

Comment: interesting indeed and works!

Comment: It doesn't return true when popups are blocked.

Comment: This does not work. The browser isn't over-writing the method. This can be proven by turning on your popup blocker and invoke a popup via the user clicking a button. The popup will succeed. On the same page, open another popup without the user's interaction, and watch the popup fail. The popup blocker is invoked based on how the popup is invoked, meaning, the browser is not modifying anything directly on the `window` object.