# programmatically determine if the popup blocker is enabled in a browser without opening the new tab

Tags: javascript, popup

Is there any way to determine if the popup blocker is enabled in a browser through JavaScript without opening the new tab?

Comment: There's also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250216/popup-detection-before-user-logs-in) which does a `window.open` but then **immediately** closes it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My apologies. I guess it dupe of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914/how-can-i-detect-if-a-browser-is-blocking-a-popup. This also address the `window.open` approach that you pointed out

Comment: @Rajesh: It would be (and also the one I linked above), except that all of the real answers there do what the OP said he/she doesn't want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can detect it without using `window.open`, so I think the short answer to your question is: No, there isn't.

The accepted answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250216/popup-detection-before-user-logs-in) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914/how-can-i-detect-if-a-browser-is-blocking-a-popup) demonstrate using `window.open` (the first then immediately closes the window). However: If the popup is blocked, the user still receives the notification of a blocked popup (at least in Chrome, but probably others as well), which I'm guessing is why you've said you don't want to use `window.open`.

So again, I think the answer to your question is: No, you can't do that.